# Why won't Daisy Oak massage my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

For the past few days, I've visited her in Pallet town between 15:00 and 16:00, and all she's done is yammer about her tea. Do I have to fulfill some other condition for her exclusive services?

Edit: Also, I *have* gotten a massage or two in the past, so I'm thinking it's some kind of timing issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for Daisy to massage your Pokémon, you need to have **beaten the Elite Four**, and **visit her between 3pm and 4pm**. Additionally, your DS knows if you have altered the time on its clock. Changing the time will void that day's time-based events, so you can't just turn your clock to 3:01pm.But if that's the only time you can make,turn it to the apropriate time so the **next day** when you come back from work you can get a massage.

Comment: Yep, I was altering the clock to get at the 3-4 time slot outside of work. I expected it to work more like AC:WW where the time is computed based on your last save and behaves correctly as long as it's moved forward. Definitely did *not* expect a whole-day void!